# Hiding container if all children are hidden in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dynamic, html-table

I am creating a number of tables dynamically, which all have a number of rows that are also created dynamically using Angular.

My goal is to have each table hidden if there are no visible rows in that table's tbody.

```
<table ng-repeat="package in listOfPackages" ng-if="this.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].childNodes.length > 0 ">
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="thing in package.things" ng-if="thing.status === 'interesting'">
      <td>{{thing.someInfo}}</td>
      <td>{{thing.someOtherInfo}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The line `ng-if="this.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].childNodes.length > 0"` seems to be my problem - I do not know the proper way to find an element's own children, and check how many it has visible.

Is there any possible way to do this in angular?

Comment: you can use a function that returns true/false depending on the conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a function in your controller something like

```
$scope.showPackageTable = function (package) {
    var toShow = false;
    for (var thing in package.things) {
        if (thing.status === 'interesting') { toShow = true; }
    }
    return toShow;
}
```

then you can use that in your html `ng-if="showPackageTable(package)"`